# Why is my FormData object empty?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, forms, xmlhttprequest

When I run

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("somekey", "somevalue");
console.log("data = " + JSON.stringify(data)); // TEST
```

I get empty braces printed to the console. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FormData API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/#formdata) doesn't include anything to expose the content of it back to the client.

It isn't empty. You just don't have a way to look at what is inside it.

The data you have appended will still appear when you `send()` it with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: How do I get that data from my controller action? If my controller is `[HttpPost] public async Task<JsonResult> upload ( )` then how do I get `somevalue` from inside that controller?

Comment: @PeterThiel — I don't even know what programming language you are using there. How you read multipart form data in your framework of choice is a completely different problem to the one you are asking about here.